# Calculating the Trace of a Matrix; Syntactical Errors

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I was tasked with writing OCAML code to calculate the Trace of a square matrix (the values inside the diagonal of a matrix). As a bonus, and for my own understanding, I'd also like to write code to produce a list of the trace of a square matrix.

I've created a tail recursive function utilizing the List.map feature which strips the first element of each row, and so on and so forth.

```ml
let trace m =
   let rec helper m acc =
      match m with
      |[] -> acc
      |(x::_) -> helper(List.map(fun(y::ys) -> ys)) (acc+x)
   in helper m 0 ;;
```

Unfortunately I believe my syntax is off and I am unsure how to go about solving this. I think I have the right theory/idea in mind but poor implementation. Any help would be greatly appreciated

This is the error I get when I run the code:

```
This expression has type 'a list list -> 'a list list but an expression was expected of type 'b list
1:Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
[]
```

Comment: What makes you think that? Do you get an error, or not the right result? What result do you expect to get for some example input?

Comment: I have updated the post to show the error I get! I really don't know how to get past this, any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As @glennsl says, you should do the work to ask a good question. You don't tell us anything about the error you see, for example. Generally you should copy/paste the error text into your question.

When I copy/paste your code I see an error for this fragment:

```
(List.map (fun (y :: ys) -> ys))
```

`List.map` takes two parameters: the first is a function, which you have. The second is a list to map over, which you don't have here. Since you don't supply a list, the value of this expression is a function that expects a list and returns the transformed list.

Since the first parameter of `helper` is a list of lists (I assume), and not a function, you have a type error. (Not a syntax error.)

Most likely you need to supply the list over which you want to map your function.

Comment: I have updated my original post. I want to supply the list of rows, in a similar fashion to this. 
```
let trace m =
let rec helper m acc =
match m with
|[] -> acc
|(x::_) rows -> helper(List.map(fun(y::ys) -> ys)rows) (acc+x)
in helper m 0 ;;
```
However I am unsure of how to properly implement it